# Редактирование строки на Go (Golang)

Tags: golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Go изменить строку: например, сделать заглавной каждую букву после подчёркивания? (А лучше провести только три такие замены.)

При чтении документации создаётся ощущение некоторой запутанности и непригодности языка к подобным задачам.

Comment: @vax, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Можно ещё регэкспами эту задачу решить:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("_(\\w)")
result := re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(text, func(s string) string { return strings.ToUpper(s) })
```

http://play.golang.org/p/OnXnzbc8MQ